# Passing arguments with "open -a Terminal"

Tags: bash, macos

It seems like it's a very stupid question.
I'm trying to open a bash-file with (another) Terminal inside a bash-file, providing two arguments.

Something like this:

```
open -a Terminal path/to/file.sh ARG1 ARG2
```

I tried something like that, which gives me no errors but simply doesn't provide the arguments:

```
open -a Terminal path/to/file.sh --args ARG1 ARG2
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Is this a global question or just asking how to open a script within another window?

Comment: just trying to open a bash-file in a new terminal window with arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean this:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "date +s"'
```

or this with arguments:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "echo 'arg2' 'arg2'"'
```

Or this way of working may suit better:

```
osascript<<EOF
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "yourScript $1 $2"
end tell
EOF
```

Comment: yeah I was thinking about apple script too, but couldn't get it right... something like this if I want to open a file with arguments?

`osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "path/to/file.sh '$1' '$2'"'`